# How to run sql statements against gitlab self-managed database running on Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: gitlab

I am running a self-managed Gitlab on a Kubernetes cluster using the [official charts](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/) and I need to run an SQL statement against gitlab's database, e.g: `ALTER TABLE application_settings ADD CONSTRAINT application_settings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);` to solve an issue `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleOrderError: Relation has no current order and table has no primary key to be used as default order`.

Maybe there's a way through the toolbox pod and using `gitlab-rails/gitlab-rake` or something else?

P.S Assuming I have no direct access to the DB and no Jump-box.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole
```

and it needs to be run inside the toolbox pod in case Gitlab is installed in a kubernetes cluster: `kubectl exec -it toolbox -- bash`

or this:

```
sudo -u gitlab-psql /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/ gitlabhq_production
```

Comment: late but true, and it needs to be run inside the toolbox pod in case gitlab installed in kubernetes cluster: `kubectl exec -it toolbox -- bash`